# Calculate the determinant of $\det(5(AB^{-2})^T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a matrix $$A =
\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & 0 & −2 & −7\\
        2 & 2 & 0 & 0\\
        0 & 0 & 1 & 3\\
        5 & 6 & 0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ Suppose that $B$ is a matrix of size $4 \times 4$ with $\det(B) = 3$. I wish to calculate $\det(5(AB^{−2})^T)$.

Now I already have the answer from book but I don't understand why it is this: $\det(5(AB^{−2})^T) = 5^4 \det((AB^{−2})^T) $.

Why did $5$ become $5^4$? I'm really confused.

Thank you!

Comment: What are the dimensions of $(AB^{-2})^\top$?

Comment: Because, if $A$ is a $n\times n$ and $\lambda$ is a scalar, then $$\det(\lambda A)=\det(\lambda I_n\cdot A)=\det(\lambda I_n)\det(A)=\ ?$$

Comment: @lastresort It was an extract from a bigger question and I believe there is no mention of the dimension in that. Also A is invertible.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes and that gives me det(5I) which I believe should be 25? Why is it 5^4 now...

Comment: @CookieJar From what I read, I believe there **is** mention of that.

Comment: @CookieJar Sorry, I was hinting at the power of $4$ coming from $(AB^{-2})^\top$ being a $4 \times 4$ matrix.

Comment: Well I will add an image of the question as well as the answer I have. Sorry.

Comment: Why should it be $25$? @CookieJar

Comment: @lastresort So the 5 follows the matrix size of whom it multiplies? And thus 5 to the power of 4?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli I think I might have a clue about it now...

Comment: Well I think I got it... It's the little things that I did not pay attention to. I will delete the question just in case nobody thinks it makes sense. Thanks yall for the prompt help!

Comment: @CookieJar You probably can't delete it at your rep; if you want it removed, flag it and use the 'moderator intervention' option.

Answer (score 1):

First $\det(cA)=c^n\det(A)$ where $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix. In your case $n=4$.

**Hints:** $\det(A)=\det(A^T)$, $(AB)^T=B^TA^T$ and $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. Finally $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$. Use these facts to solve the problem.